# Problema ao invocar método de uma classe recém carregada

Tags: java, testes, reflexão, load

Fiz um código que dinamicamente compila um arquivo java, e através do .class gerado consigo carregar essa classe, criar uma instancia e invocar os métodos dela usando o método `getDeclaredMethod()`. Até aí estava tudo bem. Mas agora estou me deparando com um erro quando tento fazer esse mesmo processo em uma classe de teste. Ela compila e carrega, mas não consigo acessar os métodos. O nome da classe é `Teste` e dentro dela tenho o método `test()`. Quando tento invocar o método `teste()` o erro que me é retornado diz: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Teste.test()`
Alguém sabe dizer porque isto está acontecendo com essa classe? Seguem os códigos:

Classe que compila e carrega arquivos java:

```
public class ReflectApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException {
        String arquivo = "/C:/teste/Teste.java";

        PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("logCompilacao.txt"));
        int resultadoCompilacao1 = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[]{arquivo},saida);
        System.out.println("Show: " + resultadoCompilacao1);


    try{

        URL classUrl;
        classUrl = new URL("file:///C:/teste/");
        URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
        Class c = ucl.loadClass("Teste");

        Object obj = c.newInstance();   
        Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("test", null);
        System.out.println(method.invoke(obj, null));


    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Classe de onde quero invocar os métodos:

```
public class Teste {

    @Test
    public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {

        ExternalClassBuilder my_class = new ExternalClassBuilder();
        Class c = my_class.run("/C:/teste/", "Operation");
        Object obj = c.newInstance();   

        Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("sum", int.class, int.class);
        System.out.println(method.invoke(obj, 1, 2));
        int numero = (int) method.invoke(obj, 1, 2);
        if(numero == 3){
            System.out.println("Método correto");
        }else{
            System.err.println("Método SUM incorreto");
            fail("Valor não corresponde ao esperado");
        }
        Method method2 = c.getDeclaredMethod("hello", null);
        System.out.println(method2.invoke(obj));    

    }

}
```

Independente do que o método `test()` faz, o problema que vejo é que o método não chega nem a ser encontrado.

Answer (score -1):

Para chamar um método direto da classe assim `Teste.test()` você precisa alterar a linha:

```
public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
```

Para:

```
public static void test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
```

A diferença é q eu adicionei o 'static' que fará seu método ser estático e assim poderá ser 'visto' em precisar estanciar a classe 'Teste'.

Caso não queira fazer a alteração acima, você precisa instanciar a classe para chamar o método, podendo ser assim:

```
Teste objTeste = new Teste();
objTeste.test();
```

Ou assim:

```
(new Teste()).test();
```

Tente a resposta e passe feedback!

Comment: Não que isso seja um erro(até porque não é) mas nem precisa envolver com parenteses essa ultima linha de código para que funcione.

Comment: Exato! Imagino que o autor seja iniciante, então achei que fica mais didático... hehe

Comment: Tentei deixar o método como static mas o erro permanece. A respeito de criar a instância, ela não é possível da forma que está explicando, pois assim estaria tentando usar a classe que foi recém compilada como um tipo. E isso não é possível porque java é uma linguagem de tipos fortes. A classe não está dentro do projeto, está fora em uma pasta qualquer. Só consigo instanciar a classe usando essa linha: Object obj = c.newInstance(); E pra invocar o método dela, só usando o getDeclaredMethod()

Comment: E você não consegue chamar o método no objeto instanciado por `c.newInstance()`?

Comment: Exatamente. É esse o erro que estou relatando. Pela mensagem de erro me parece que por algum motivo o método não é encontrado

Comment: Tente alterar `c.getDeclaredMethod("test", null);` por `c.getMethod("test");`

Comment: Não funciona, já tentei isso.

Comment: Cara, então eu só posso te ajudar reproduzindo no IDE, e no momento não posso. Caso ainda não tenha uma resposta que resolva até eu chegar em casa, te ajudo.

Comment: A resposta foi bem intencionada, mas ela perdeu totalmente o ponto da pergunta. O AP não é iniciante, nem tão pouco o que ele está querendo fazer pode ser considerado algo simples.